# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree at installing NgRx in Angular 15

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am currently having an issue trying to install NgRx in my Angular 15 project.

I am using a single command:

```
 ng add @ngrx/store@latest
```

and I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myProject-ui@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"~7.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/core@15.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!     @angular/core@"^15.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from @ngrx/store@15.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ngrx/store
npm ERR!       @ngrx/store@"15.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.5.0" from @ngrx/store@15.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngrx/store
npm ERR!   @ngrx/store@"15.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full 
report
```

I am not 100% sure what the problem could be, maybe someone has already faced this issue before.

I am using latest Angular version

```
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `rxjs` deps to at least `7.5` which is required by `@ngrx/store@15.3.0`.

The other alternative being a force install with `npm i --force` or